# "current" class on top level menu item with wp_nav_menu

Tags: php, wordpress

I've created a wordpress menu with wp_nav_menu.

my structure looks like:

- Page

  - Category
- Page
- Page
- Page

If I open a post in "Category", there is no "current" class on the top level of the menu – only on "Category". Nesting only with pages works fine on multi level menus.

Is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ahh... found the solution in the wordpress codex. this works fine for me:

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'add_menu_parent_class' );
function add_menu_parent_class( $items ) {

    $parents = array();
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        if ( $item->menu_item_parent && $item->menu_item_parent > 0 ) {
            $parents[] = $item->menu_item_parent;
        }
    }

    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        if ( in_array( $item->ID, $parents ) ) {
            $item->classes[] = 'menu-parent-item'; 
        }
    }

    return $items;    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1) Either write a custom walker http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Using_a_Custom_Walker_Function to add a current class when that category is called;

2) Or, (not the most elegant): find your page ID for the menu item you want - `1000` in the example below - to highlight as current, select that category - `is_category` - and then add the current class - `addClass` -  with jQuery:

```
<?php if (is_category('my-category')) { ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        jQuery(function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#menu-main-menu li.menu-item-1000').addClass('current-menu-item');
        }); });

        </script>

    <?php } ?>
```